# Regex Expression pattern to check multiple latitudes and longitudes values

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex pattern:

```js
^POLYGON\s*\(\((\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\)\)$
```

I am trying to match the string pattern **POLYGON ((77.40970726940513 12.978147980713118,77.37585259873805 13.273612877088299,77.80253462545315 13.185991361443607,77.83326404994843 12.874112460078642,77.60553384375903 12.753157552741165,77.47003961302485 12.860758717988348,77.40044069330365 12.989005488377385,77.40970726940513 12.978147980713118))**.
But the regex pattern which I have used above only satisfies the string with values POLYGON ((130.55809472656256 111.333)) .

Need a help on regex expression to match the string like above with multiple lat long values with comma separated groups.

Comment: Try `^POLYGON\s*\(\((?>(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,(?!\)\)))?)*\)\)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally repeat the second part of the pattern and match either a comma or a whitespace char to match the whole string.

```
^POLYGON\s*\(\(\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[,\s]\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*\)\)$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ePOLYGON%5cs*%5c%28%5c%28%5c-%3f%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5b%2c%5cs%5d%5c-%3f%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%29*%5c%29%5c%29%5cr%3f%24&i=POLYGON+%28%2877.40970726940513+12.978147980713118%2c77.37585259873805+13.273612877088299%2c77.80253462545315+13.185991361443607%2c77.83326404994843+12.874112460078642%2c77.60553384375903+12.753157552741165%2c77.47003961302485+12.860758717988348%2c77.40044069330365+12.989005488377385%2c77.40970726940513+12.978147980713118%29%29%0d%0a%0d%0aPOLYGON+%28%28130.55809472656256+111.333%29%29&o=m)

If they should come in pairs separated by a whitespace char and after lat long a comma, you can optionally repeat the pairs:

```
^POLYGON\s*\(\(\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s\-?\d+\.\d+)?)*\)\)$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ePOLYGON%5cs*%5c%28%5c%28%5c-%3f%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%5cs%5c-%3f%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%28%3f%3a%2c-%3f%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5cs%5c-%3f%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%29%3f%29*%5c%29%5c%29%5cr%3f%24&i=POLYGON+%28%2877.40970726940513+12.978147980713118%2c77.37585259873805+13.273612877088299%2c77.80253462545315+13.185991361443607%2c77.83326404994843+12.874112460078642%2c77.60553384375903+12.753157552741165%2c77.47003961302485+12.860758717988348%2c77.40044069330365+12.989005488377385%2c77.40970726940513+12.978147980713118%29%29%0d%0a%0d%0aPOLYGON+%28%28130.55809472656256+111.333%29%29%0d%0a%0d%0aPOLYGON+%28%28130.55809472656256%29%29&o=m)